# How to set ASP.NET label text to current user name

Tags: asp.net, terminology, parse-error

I am trying to set a user name to a label,
but not sure if this is the right syntax - 
adding following markup generates a parse error

```
<asp:Label ID="userNameLabel" runat="server"
     Text='<%= User.Identity.Name.Split(new char[]{'\\'})[1] %>' />
```

The main problem here is that, I do not know what `<%= %>` or `<%# %>` are called, thus cannot  Google/Bing.

Can someone point me to a right direction?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc).aspx

Comment: @ChristopheD: I'd have choosen your link as answer, if you had posted it as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would set the text of the label in the code behind in Page_Load

```
userNameLabel.Text = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
```

You will need to ensure that there is a \ in the username or you will get an error.

Comment: For now, this is what I settled with.  Thanks RR

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to convert User.Identity.Name into a couple of strings, it looks changing char[] to string[], should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The <%# %> syntax is for data binding. It will work for what you want to do, you will need to make sure that DataBind() is called.

```
<asp:Label ID="userNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1] %>' />
```

Other options include:

Set the Text property from the Page_Load event.

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userNameLabel.Text = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
}
```

Wrap the label around the write.

```
<asp:Label ID="userNameLabel" runat="server"><%= User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1] %></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as well.

```
    <asp:Label ID="userNameLabel" runat="server">
        <%= User.Identity.Name %>
    </asp:Label>
```